# Laravel: Connection error PDO

Tags: database, laravel, pdo

I have made my controller to insert data into my database and Task is the model file.

app/http/controller/UsersTableController:

```
public function store() {
    $user = new Task;
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->PhoneNo = Input::get('PhoneNo');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','You have been successfully subscribe to us.');
}
```

Task model:

```
<?php
    namespace App;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   class Task extends \Eloquent
   {
       protected $table ='users';
       public $timestamp =  'false';
   }
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/PostForm', array('uses'=>'UsersTable@store'));
```

and my form through which I want to save the data into data base saved as Register.blade.php

```
<form action="PostForm" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Phone Number: <input type="number" name="PhoneNo"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" mak=8>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
</form>
```

and what I'm getting on my browser screen when I'm pressing submit button....

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into users (name, PhoneNo, password, updated_at, created_at) values (romiii, 9876543210, asderf, 2015-12-23 10:02:56, 2015-12-23 10:02:56))

and

> PDOException in Connection.php line 390: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

To stop Eloquent from automatically handling timestamps, you need to set the `$timestamps` attribute to false.

`public $timestamps = false`

Note that you're setting it to a *string*, which does not evaluate to a boolean false.

Comment: But, Is my method in the controller that I have made to inserty the data into database is correct?

Comment: Yes it is, but that's not where the problem is, please read my answer again and mark it as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: This worked for me. I think its a security option to save updated_time as a default value in every table.